# VueJS how to listen of a sequence of keys?

Tags: keylistener, vuejs2

How do I use VueJS 2 to respond to a sequence of keypresses? For example, if a person presses the keys:

A B R A C A D A B R A

in exactly this order, I want to listen on this sequence + change the webpage in some way in response to this. I am aware of https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html but that page seems to only allow mouse clicks and input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

There are [Key-Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) event as well, you can probably save all these input in a variable and keep matching with this pattern.

Comment: Seems to only work with inputs. I want to bind it to the whole page itself.

Comment: @Ben In that case you may have to use `$(window).keydown` only.